# Why regex "^[0-9]|1[1-2]" match "13" or "33" or "5632" or

Tags: c++, regex, match

Why regex "^[0-9]|1[1-2]" match "13" or "33" or "5632" or...?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <regex.h>

main() {
    regex_t regex;
    char *reg = "^[0-9]|1[0-2]";
    int reti = regcomp(&regex,reg, REG_NEWLINE | REG_EXTENDED);
    char *meses[] = {"enero","enero","febrero","marzo","abril",
     "mayo","junio","julio","agosto","setiembre",
     "octubre","noviembre","diciembre"};
    char mes[3];
    puts("Ingrese numero de mes [1-12]:");
    fgets(mes,sizeof(mes),stdin);
    if(!regexec(&regex, mes, 0, NULL, 0)) printf("El mes es: %s\n",meses[atoi(mes)]);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: This is not related to C++.

Comment: @jamesdlin: Shouldn't be necessary, `|` has the lowest precedence of all.

Comment: `mes` is only 3 bytes long, and the final byte is needed for the terminating `'\0'`. How did you manage to fit `"5632"` into it? Hint: You didn't; add some code to show the value of `mes`. If you make `mes` big enough to hold a line of input, `fgets` will leave the newline `'\n'` in the string; that's likely to cause problems.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex needs some tweaks.

You have to use this regex

```
^([0-9]|1[1-2])$
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/qB6fE2/1)**

[image]

The alternation operator (or OR operator) has the lowest precedence of all regex operators. So, you were matching

```
  ^[0-9]
or
  1[1-2]
```

That's why you matched `1` in `13`, `3` in `33` or `5` in `5632`.

On the other hand, with this regex     `^([0-9]|1[1-2])$` you will match numbers from `0` to `9` or `11` to `12` thanks to the anchors (`^` and `$`) and the usage of parentheses.

Edit: as **[Maarten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2440280/maarten-hilferink)** commented, your regex also missed October, so you would need to tweak it to:

```
^([0-9]|1[0-2])$
```

Comment: What about octubre? And I would disallow 0. Thus: ^([1-9]|1[0-2])$

Comment: @MaartenHilferink good eye man. I didn't noticed about that I focused on the wrong pattern instead. I've updated the answer at the bottom. Btw, I left the 0 as allowed since that's OP original regex, he can decide that